# Error in deploying code in Qt 5.2.1 for the Android device with API 19

Tags: android, qt

Does Qt 5.2.1 supports Android API level 19?I am trying to build an app for Google Nexus 5.My code is building fine but while deploying to the simulator,its showing error.The same thing I tried for the API 18 but it works.Can anyone clarify my doubt why this API 19 is not working and working for the API 18??

Comment: pls post the error message! here is an detailed tutorial how to deploy qt apps on android: http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.8/creator-deploying-android.html

Comment: Error while building/deploying project practiseTwo (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.8, Qt 5.2.1))
When executing step 'Deploy to Android device'.                    In General message panel I am getting this- 
Warnings while parsing qmltypes information of C:/QtMobile/5.2.1/android_armv7/qml/QtQuick/Enterprise/Controls:
76:9: Expected only name, prototype, defaultProperty, attachedType, exports and exportMetaObjectRevisions script bindings.